# Views show in Eclipse layout editor but not on a tablet device

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

This is my layout for listview row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="190dip"
android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
android:background="@drawable/feed_bg_new"
android:minHeight="190dip" >

<!--
first two hex digits in background color are for alpha  android:background="#E6FFFFFF"
android:cacheColorHint="#E6FFFFFF" >
-->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/q_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/subjectNameTv"
    android:layout_below="@+id/subjectNameTv"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:autoLink="none"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="Seminarska naloga o letalih hldffgdfgdfgdfgdfggkldfkjgldgjldfjgdlfgkj slkdfsdlfsldkfsldf sdlfkjslkdfsd"
    android:textColor="#4D4D4D"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subjectNameTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:text="Slovenščina"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/clock_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/commentBtn"
    android:background="@drawable/time_bg"
    android:text="15 min"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/star_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/clock_text"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/clock_text"
    android:background="@drawable/star_bg"
    android:text="1350555"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/quoteLine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/q_avatar"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:src="@drawable/quote_line" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/doneBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/q_avatar"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:background="@drawable/done_button_selector"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="3/15"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/likeButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/doneBtn"
    android:background="@drawable/like_button_selector"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="10"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/commentBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/likeButton"
    android:background="@drawable/comment_button_selector"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="2"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/q_user"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/q_avatar"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/q_avatar"
    android:text="Marko Novak"
    android:textColor="#8F8F8F" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/q_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/q_user"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/commentBtn"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/q_user"
    android:text="|9:30"
    android:textColor="#8F8F8F" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/q_avatar"
    android:layout_width="20dip"
    android:layout_height="20dip"
    android:layout_above="@+id/doneBtn"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/q_title"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/xerox" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that ImageViews q_avatar, quoteLine and TextViews q_user, q_time show in Eclipse ADT layout editor but not on my tablet device.

What could be wrong?

Comment: put RelativeLayout  in scrollview. Probably the height that you have given 190dip is not able to fit in all the components.

Comment: I tried your layout on my tablet device and all the views are visible.. !! I just tried it by replacing your images by `ic_launcher.png`. Just try that out. If it works fine then some problem with your images... perhaps ..

Comment: Different image doesnt help.